# Is D minor also F Aeolian?

Tags: modes, key-signatures

If I were to write a song in D minor, could I notate it correctly in F Aeolian? Because the subsequent 4th of the root in F Aeolian would be flat, right? Therefore, D minor and F Aeolian, which in different keys like C Aeolian and A minor are the same, would be different by the B flat? Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I wonder if you beat Ionian (major) rather than Aeolian (minor).

Comment: @Aaron I wonder if you mean "mean" (want to say) rather than "beat" (strike).   ;-)

Comment: While I don't suppose this answers your question, it's worth noting that in the days before Aeolian had been invented, pieces that we'd consider "minor" today were Dorian, but the sixth degree of the scale could be major or minor, that is, B natural or B flat when the center is D.  (Indeed, the same is true today, only we use terms like "natural minor" and "melodic minor" to deal with this variability.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Natural) Minor and Aeolian are two words describing the same scale, as are Major and Ionian.

D minor/aeolian and F major/ionian share the same key signature: Bb.

A minor/aeolian and C major/ionian share the same key signature: no sharps or flats.

These major/minor (ionian/aeolian) pairs are called *relative modes*, meaning that they share the same key signatures.

The third note of a minor/aeolian scale is the first note of the corresponding (*relative*) major/ionian scale. The sixth note of a major/ionian scale is the first note of the corresponding (*relative*) minor/aeolian scale.

Comment: I think should be added to answer the title no.

Answer (score 15):

## Key and mode are not the same thing.

In a mode (in the modern/current meaning of the word), your tonic (home note, center pitch) and the **intervals around it are fixed** in rigid positions, and if you play pitches not included in the fixed set, clearly enough to make a harmonic impact, you're not in the mode anymore.

In a key, only your tonic is fixed, and the third above it, when the harmony is at home, resting at the center of balance. In minor keys it's a minor third above tonic, and in major keys it's a major third above tonic (home note). But **all the rest of the intervals can and often do change along the way**. However, a key has a **default set of notes/pitches**, which is denoted by a **key signature**, and in a minor key, the default set of notes/pitches is the same as in the corresponding Aeolian. But in a key, there can be chromatic alterations, but the listener's feeling still remaining in the same key. The chromatic alterations are denoted with temporary **accidentals**.

If your sense of tonic does not change, i.e. where home is and if home is minor or major, the key does not change. But if the intervals around the tonic change, the mode changes.

You can have the chords Dm, E7, A7, Dm, in a tune that's in the key of D minor. During the E7 chord, the G note is temporarily sharpened to G#, and during the A7 chord, the C note is temporarily sharpened to C#. But you **cannot have that in D Aeolian mode**. In a mode, there are no chromatic alterations of notes. Inside a mode, you stick to the given intervals around the tonic and do not change them.

If your song is in D minor, chances are that it will use pitches outside D Aeolian, particularly C#, which is the so-called leading tone for D. And then you'll need to write temporary **accidentals** in addition to the key signature. **Some people would even go as far as to say, if you do NOT raise the C to C# anywhere in the song, your song is not properly in D minor, because there's no leading tone.**

Furthermore, the key signature of D minor has the notes of D Aeolian, not F Aeolian. F Aeolian has F, G, Ab, Bb, C, Db, Eb.

---

### With pictures

Edit. The above was apparently not clear enough. I'll try once more, with pictures.

In traditional Western harmony thinking, there are seven scale degrees and a tonal center, tonic. The tonal center is a center of balance - you're supposed to feel when the music's harmony is "at home", resting. (In addition to the tonic being a note, it has a major/minor dimension to it, an expectation of a third being suitable beside the tonic at the resting position.) Each of the scale degrees can be thought to be like a switch that can be in natural, sharp or flat setting. (Let's not worry about double-flat and double-sharp etc. now.)

[image: Seven scale degrees and tonal center]

A **key signature** specifies settings for the seven scale degrees, but it does not say where the tonal center is. The notes you hear make you feel something about the tonal center. And it is entirely possible to use the same set of seven notes and set the tonal center to any of the notes, in the listener's mind. For some scale degrees it might take more skill than for others, but it's possible. If you feel that D is the tonal center - as you do if your song is, say, in D minor key, then the D note has special meaning to you:

[image: D minor scale degrees]

Additionally, you can write temporary **accidentals**, which change a staff position to something different than what was specified by the key signature. For example, if you started with one flat, i.e. Bb and the rest of the scale degrees in natural, but you play an A7 chord, you'll most likely consider the C note as being switched to sharp position, at least for the duration of the chord. Look what happened to the C note's switch:

[image: D minor with C#]

You might think something different about other scale degrees if you want, but **the sounding pitches don't explicate things** about the other notes. If you strongly PLAY a B natural, then the B scale degree's switch in your mind tends to get switched to natural position. You can think that you have *harmonic context* in your mind, consisting of a set of switches that change between sharp/natural/flat, according to what pitches you hear.

When you're "in a key", you can freely switch the scale degrees to different sharp/flat/natural positions, **as long as you don't mess with the feeling of tonal center**. If the tonal center moves, then the key changed. That's called a *modulation*.

Ok, what's a mode then? To stay in a mode, you are NOT free to change scale degrees, and you are NOT free to move the tonal center either. Be careful what you play, if you want to stay in the mode. The swithes should be like they had been superglued in place:

[image: D Aeolian superglued]

If you DO mess with any of the settings, then you **break the mode** and you're no longer in the same mode. Let's say you play a C# note. Not D Aeolian anymore.

[image: broken mode]

Comment: 'The key has a default set of notes/pitches, which is denoted by the key signature.' Not sure that rings true for minors.

Comment: This is a good description of the modern meaning of "mode."  In the earlier incarnation of modal music, however, from the middle ages through the baroque -- but mostly in the renaissance -- modal music admitted chromatic alteration without losing its modal identity (which led to the major/minor tonal system).  In the middle ages, for example, there was no Aeolian mode, and a piece in Dorian would typically have both B flats and B naturals (with a D final).  In the baroque, you can fin harmonizations of modal melodies that have chromatic alterations but can't be analyzed as major or minor.

Comment: @Tim wouldn't you say that the natural minor is the default set of pitches?  Granted, it's largely a "lie told to children," but like most of those there's a fair amount of truth to it.

Comment: Natural minor *may* be the default set, but in minor *keys* the 6th and 7th notes are often raised, thus not following the key signature (unless it's Bartok) but would still be 'in key'.

Comment: @Tim but that's what "default" means, isn't it?  A default is normally one way but often different.

Comment: @Tim default pitches is what you get, if you don't make any changes with accidentals. Like when something is in default settings. I don't have any better word for it. In D minor you have one flat, as defined by the key signature, if nothing further is said. If you raise the 6th or the 7th, you have to explicitly say so by adding accidentals.

Comment: Truly not certain! But probably correct. Although there are many, many minor pieces with at least every leading note needing that accidental, making it, at least for me, an intrinsic part of the key - but not key sig.

Comment: @Tim right, this is the lie-told-to-children aspect (though it also has a real historical basis).  There's certainly an argument that the "default" seventh degree in minor is raised, but adapting the key signature system to reflect that would disrupt several centuries of practice.  So the notational default is a lowered seventh degree even if the tonal-music default is raised.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it's a nice description of a topic which is often very messy

Comment: @Tim, The minor key is described by the key signature and the mutability of steps 6 and 7. Some texts (but I don't remember which) even include both versions of steps 6 and 7 as "diatonic."  I'm not sure how these texts handled raised 7 with lowered 7.

Comment: To be clear: the central claim here is that a "mode" only includes 7 pitches/notes (the ones that would be diatonic in the relative major/ionian), whereas a "key" includes all 12 chromatic pitches of a 12-tone system? And that a "key" is thus only about classifying those pitches relative to the tonic, but a "mode" explicitly selects a subset? Actually, is there anything else being said here that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not at all. Total, catastrophic misunderstanding. My failure to communicate this idea is in cosmological scale. Galaxies were derailed. If you wait for some time, I'll try to draw pictures.

Comment: Let me at least test the premises first: does a mode "include" pitches? Does a key?

Comment: This is why it can be useful, in more stringent music theory contexts, to replace the layman's term "key" with "tonality." C major and A minor are "keys," and we learn about them along with our key signatures and circle of fifths. But to say that we "have a tonal center of C" allows us to mess around with modal mixture etc., without anybody freaking out about "But the key signature says..."

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I drew pictures for you, does it make more sense now? It's not maths, it's culture. "Key" etc. are really only words that people use to describe things they do. They might do something different than others, or they might describe what they do differently. Anything we say here, only makes sense in a practical context, when someone _does_ something. In a certain harmonic style I call "modal" playing, the scale degrees and the tonic are fixed. There are other styles, and there is more than one way to describe the practices, and people do not agree 100% on the meanings of the words.

Comment: The pictures are fantastic. Please draw pictures in all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

> If I were to write a song in D minor, could I notate it correctly in F Aeolian?

I think you meant `F` Ionian or `F` major, and you mean the key signatures involved.

So, could a song in `D` minor, which would normally have a key signature of one flat, be written with a `F` Ionian/`F` major key signature of one flat? Yes, both key signatures use one flat.

> Is D minor also F Aeolian?

Again, assuming you meant `F` Ionian: no, they are not the same.

They each have different tonics and modes.

`D` minor has a tonic of `D` and a mode of minor.

`F` Ionian has a tonic of `F` and a mode of Ionian (major.)

Additionally, the dominant seventh chord of each will be different.

`D` minor has a dominant of `A7`.

`F` major has a dominant of `C7`.

Keys are determined by tonic/dominant harmony, not key signatures.

Some types of modal music - like folk and Renaissance music - work in a similar way but may use other chords as a dominant such as `♭VII` or `iv` rather than `V`. But the point still remains: the *tonality* (for lack of a better term, the modal "key") will be determined by the interaction of tonic and modal dominant chords.

One other point. You should understand and make clear whether you mean music that is actually in a *minor key* or a modal style of harmony in aeolian mode. Using "in minor" and "in aeolian" as interchangeable terms is wrong and confusing. It doesn't have immediate impact on your question, but it makes a jumble of the terminology and concepts of tonality. That could make it hard to understand your intentions if the topic is harmony and tonality.

Comment: "You should understand and make clear whether you mean music that is actually in a minor key or a modal style of harmony in aeolian mode." I'm pretty sure *the entire reason the question is being asked* is because OP didn't perceive those two things as being different.

Answer (score 1):

No, D minor is the name of a key which is highly compatible with the D Aeolian scale.

"F Aeolian" is not a term which means "the Aeolian mode relative to F major". However, yes, D Aeolian is a mode of the F major scale, or F Ionian.

"F Aeolian" has the simplest possible meaning: the Aeolian mode starting on the F root note. Music emphasizing F Aeolian would be most likely be identified as being in the F minor key.

Answer (score -1):

I think simple answer should be NO. D minor is also D aeolian which is not F aeolian.